# In PHP if you include a file that itself includes another file, will the first file contain both of the other files?

Tags: php, include

In PHP, if you include a file that itself includes another file, will the first file contain both of the other files?

Comment: Including files doesn't change what a file contains, but it does load code into PHP's memory.

Comment: In PHP, `Includes` are way to organize and reuse data. If you include a file that includes a file that includes a file etc it renders it as if all of the files were hard coded into your original document.

Comment: @Brad: What, write 3 lines of code??? But that would be so much easier than asking on Stack Overflow! It would practically be cheating! No offense to you, SouthCode - it's good to ask, but good science is based on experimentation.

Answer (score 6):

It's pretty straight forward: Yes.

If A includes B, and B includes C, A effectively includes both B and C.

Comment: Of course the next question is what happens when C includes A and we get a cycle?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, if you are on `file0.php` and you include `file1.php` which includes `file2.php`, file0.php will now contain `file1.php` and `file2.php`